# R: how to export and import `coxph` (or `cph`) result?

Tags: r, prediction, survival-analysis, cox-regression

For prediction need, I want to save a `coxph` or `cph` model to be able use it in my function.
So my question is how to save the all `coxph` (or `cph`) object and then how to load it when needed?
The object will be used in the `predictCox` function (library `riskRegression`)

```
library(survival)
library(data.table)
library(riskRegression)

#### generate data ####
set.seed(10)
d <- sampleData(40,outcome="survival") ## training dataset
nd <- sampleData(4,outcome="survival") ## validation dataset
d$time <- round(d$time,1) ## create tied events
fit <- coxph(Surv(time,event)~X1 +  X6,
             data=d, ties="breslow", x = TRUE, y = TRUE)

## compute individual specific cumulative hazard and survival probabilities 
fit.pred <- predictCox(fit, newdata=nd, times=3, se = TRUE, band = TRUE)
```

Comment: is `saveRDS(model, file = "mymodel_name.rds")` what you're looking for?

Comment: Also, you can use `dput(fit)` to generate R code able to reproduce the object itself

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was what I needed exactly! suschiChef: if you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `save` function to store R objects in a file. If you want to store a single R object you should use the extension `.rds` and `saveRDS` function. On other hand, if you want to store several objects you should use the `.Rdata` file extension.

**Examples**

Single object:

`saveRDS(model, file="model.rds")`

`model <- readRDS(file="model.rds")`

In this case the object name is not stored, so you need to use the `readRDS` function and assign `<-` the object to a new variable in your environment.

Multiple objects:

`save(model1, model2, df, file = "models_and_data.RData")`

If you want to save all objects currently in your work environment you can call `save.image` instead:

`save.image(file="project_image.RData")`

In both cases all objects are saved with their original name, so you can load them into your environment with the `load` function without assigning new names:

`load(file="models_and_data.RData")`

Beware that some implementations of `coxph` make a copy of the data to model object (check if your model object has `model` in its structure, i.e `model$model`). If you are working with sensitive data and need to export models, make sure you are not exporting sensitive data hidden in the object.

Source: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html